# Access 2000 automaticly add text to a form entry field

Tags: database, ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2000 database with a custom form.  People are entering info into this.  On one of the fields I want to automatically append a ".zip" to one of the fields.

How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a textBox called txtFileName, then you can use its AfterUpdate event to do this:

```
Private Sub txtFileName_AfterUpdate()
    If Not IsNull(txtFileName) Then
        txtFileName = Trim$(txtFileName)
        If Not Right$(txtFileName, 4) = ".zip" Then
            txtFileName = txtFileName & ".zip"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's not working..?  Private Sub FirstName_AfterUpdate()
If Not IsNull(FirstName) Then FirstName = Trim$(FirstName)
If Not Right$(FirstName, 4) = ".zip" Then FirstName = FirstName & ".zip"
End If
End If
End Sub

Comment: Its working for me...  There must be some other factor, external to my code.  What happens with you?